# Codeception:how to color test message

Tags: php, codeception

I want to color message.
If test passed then output message color green else red.

```
 $I = $this->apiTester;  //$this->apiTester is instance of ApiTester.php Class

    if ($outputData['success'] == true) {        //$outputdata is json array
        $I->comment("see test status:Passed.");  //I want its color green
    } else {
        $I->comment("see test status:Failed.");  //I want its color red
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$I->comment("\e[0m\e[35msee test status:Failed.\e[0m");
```

[ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors)

Comment: Valentim this is a nice idea but it does not work. Do this and you will  just see:  \e[0m\e[35msee test status:Failed.\e[0m in the terminal without colors

Answer (score 0):

A good solution to do this is to create a new Color.php Helper class in your  _support/Helper directory of Codeception using [this class](https://gist.github.com/superbrothers/3431198) and modifying the namespace to:
namespace Helper;

Then you can just use it like this in your tests:

```
$I->comment(\Helper\Color::set("see test status:Failed.", "red");
```